# How would I add a loop that counts the current number of open ports?

Tags: loops, sockets, for-loop, port, counter

This program scans my local machine and finds all open ports. It returns finds what port is open and prints a statement that shows the port. I need to add a counter loop that actively counts the current number of open ports. My code is as follows:

```
public class LowPortScanner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int maxPort = 1024;   // It takes forever to scan all 65536 ports
    String host = "localhost";

    System.err.println("This is an error message");

    if (args.length > 0) {
      host = args[0];
    }
    System.out.println("Scanning ports on " + host + "...");
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxPort; i++) {
      try {
        Socket s = new Socket(host, i);
        // If we get this far, we were able to open the socket. Someone is listening
        System.out.println("There is a something listening on port " + i + " of " + host);
        // Now close it because all we cared about was trying to open it..
        s.close();
      }
      catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        break;
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        // There must not be a server on this port
        // We will eat this exception because it will happen too many times.
      }
    }   // end for  
    int portCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; portCount > 0; i++) {
        portCount = i + portCount;
        System.out.println("There are currently " + i + " ports open");
    }
  }  // end main
}  // end PortScanner
```

The counter that I was working on is

```
    int portCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; portCount > 0; i++) {
        portCount = i + portCount;
        System.out.println("There are currently " + i + " ports open");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to count the open ports, the loop you've written now won't do anything useful.

You should initialize the counter before the loop where you're going to check all of the ports.

Then when a port is open (where you print that the port is open) increment the counter by 1. After the loop is finished you can print the counter which has the total number of opened ports.

It would look something like this.

```java
public class LowPortScanner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int maxPort = 1024;   // It takes forever to scan all 65536 ports
    String host = "localhost";

    System.err.println("This is an error message");

    if (args.length > 0) {
      host = args[0];
    }
    int portCount = 0; //initialize the counter
    System.out.println("Scanning ports on " + host + "...");
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxPort; i++) {
      try {
        Socket s = new Socket(host, i);
        // If we get this far, we were able to open the socket. Someone is listening
        System.out.println("There is a something listening on port " + i + " of " + host);
        // Now close it because all we cared about was trying to open it..
        portCount++; //port is open so increase counter
        s.close();
      }
      catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        break;
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        // There must not be a server on this port
        // We will eat this exception because it will happen too many times.
      }
    }   // end for  
    //print amount of open ports
    System.out.println("There are currently " + portCount + " ports open");

  }  // end main
}  // end PortScanner
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually moved the print statement inside the loop so it updates every time a loop is found.